Polynomial.java - multiplication algorithms: naïve, Karatsuba, FFT
Intro
This post is a supplement to Polynomial.java - a Java class for dealing with polynomials with BigDecimal coefficients. It presents the three polynomial multiplication algorithms. Given two polynomials: one of degree \$n_1\$, and another one of degree \$n_2\$, the multiplication algorithms are:

Naïve: running in \$\Theta(n_1 n_2)\$,
Karatsuba: running in \$\Theta(\max(n_1, n_2)^{1.58})\$,
FFT: running in \$\Theta(N \log N)\$, where \$N\$ is the closest (from above) power of \$2\$ to the \$\max(n_1, n_2)\$.

Code
com.github.coderodde.math.PolynomialMultiplier.java:
package com.github.coderodde.math;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This class contains some polynomial multiplication algorithms.
 * 
 * @version 1.1.1 (Nov 24, 2024)
 * @since 1.0.0 (Nov 22, 2024)
 */
public final class PolynomialMultiplier {
    
    public static final BigDecimal DEFAULT_EPSILON = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.01);
    public static final int DEFAULT_SCALE = 6;
    
    /**
     * Multiplies {@code p1} and {@code p2} naively in {@code O(NM)} time.
     * 
     * @param p1 the first polynomial.
     * @param p2 the second polynomial.
     * 
     * @return the product of {@code p1} and {@code p2}.
     */
    public static Polynomial multiplyViaNaive(final Polynomial p1,
                                              final Polynomial p2) {
        final int coefficientArrayLength = p1.length()
                                         + p2.length()
                                         - 1;
        
        final BigDecimal[] coefficientArray = 
                new BigDecimal[coefficientArrayLength];
        
        // Initialize the result coefficient array:
        Arrays.fill(
                coefficientArray, 
                0, 
                coefficientArrayLength, 
                BigDecimal.ZERO);
        
        for (int index1 = 0;
                 index1 < p1.length(); 
                 index1++) {
            
            for (int index2 = 0; 
                     index2 < p2.length(); 
                     index2++) {
                
                final BigDecimal coefficient1 = p1.getCoefficient(index1);
                final BigDecimal coefficient2 = p2.getCoefficient(index2);
                
                coefficientArray[index1 + index2] = 
                        coefficientArray[index1 + index2]
                        .add(coefficient1.multiply(coefficient2));
            }
        }
        
        return new Polynomial(coefficientArray);
    }
    
    /**
     * Multiplies the two input polynomials in {@code O(N^(1.58)} time where 
     * {@code N} is the degree-bound of both {@code p1} and {@code p2}. This
     * implementation is adopted from 
     * <a href="https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~deepc/LecNotes/cs31/lec6.pdf">
     * these lecture slides</a>.
     * 
     * @param p1 the first polynomial.
     * @param p2 the second polynomial.
     * @param epsilon the epsilon value for detecting zero coefficients.
     * 
     * @return the product of the two input polynomials.
     */
    public static Polynomial multiplyViaKaratsuba(Polynomial p1,
                                                  Polynomial p2,
                                                  final BigDecimal epsilon) {
        
        final int n = Math.max(p1.length(), 
                               p2.length());
        
        p1 = p1.setLength(n);
        p2 = p2.setLength(n);
        
        final Polynomial rawPolynomial = multiplyViaKaratsubaImpl(p1, p2);
        
        return rawPolynomial.minimizeDegree(epsilon);
    }
    
    /**
     * Delegates the multiplication 
     * {@link #multiplyViaKaratsuba(com.github.coderodde.math.Polynomial, com.github.coderodde.math.Polynomial, java.math.BigDecimal)}.
     * Uses the default epsilon value of {@code 0.01} for zero comparisons.
     * 
     * @param p1 the first polynomial.
     * @param p2 the second polynomial.
     * 
     * @return the product of the two input polynomials.
     */
    public static Polynomial multiplyViaKaratsuba(Polynomial p1,
                                                  Polynomial p2) {
        return multiplyViaKaratsuba(p1, p2, DEFAULT_EPSILON);
    }
    
    /**
     * Multiplies the two input polynomials in {@code O(N log N} time where 
     * {@code N} is the degree-bound of both {@code p1} and {@code p2}. This
     * implementation is adopted from 
     * <a href="https://archive.org/details/introduction-to-algorithms-third-edition-2009/page/898/mode/1up?view=theater">
     * Introduction to Algorirthms, 3rd edition, Chapter 30</a>.
     * 
     * @param p1 the first polynomial.
     * @param p2 the second polynomial.
     * @param scale the scale to use for {@link java.math.BigDecimal} values.
     * @param epsilon the epsilon value for detecting zero coefficients.
     * 
     * @return the product of the two input polynomials.
     */
    public static Polynomial multiplyViaFFT(Polynomial p1,
                                            Polynomial p2,
                                            final int scale,
                                            final BigDecimal epsilon) {
        
        final int length = Math.max(p1.length(), 
                                    p2.length());
        
        final int n = Utils.getClosestUpwardPowerOfTwo(length) * 2;
        
        p1 = p1.setLength(n);
        p2 = p2.setLength(n);
        
        ComplexPolynomial a = computeFFT(new ComplexPolynomial(p1), scale);
        ComplexPolynomial b = computeFFT(new ComplexPolynomial(p2), scale);
        ComplexPolynomial c = multiplyPointwise(a, b);
        ComplexPolynomial r = computeInverseFFT(c, scale);
        
        return r.convertToPolynomial().minimizeDegree(epsilon);
    }
    
    /**
     * Delegates the multiplication 
     * {@link #multiplyViaFFT(com.github.coderodde.math.Polynomial, com.github.coderodde.math.Polynomial, java.math.BigDecimal)}.
     * Uses the default epsilon value of {@code 0.01} for zero comparisons.
     * 
     * @param p1 the first polynomial.
     * @param p2 the second polynomial.
     * 
     * @return the product of the two input polynomials.
     */
    public static Polynomial multiplyViaFFT(final Polynomial p1,
                                            final Polynomial p2) {
        
        return multiplyViaFFT(p1, p2, DEFAULT_SCALE, DEFAULT_EPSILON);
    }
    
    private static ComplexPolynomial 
        multiplyPointwise(final ComplexPolynomial a,
                          final ComplexPolynomial b) {
        
        final ComplexPolynomial c = new ComplexPolynomial(a.length());
        
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {
            c.setCoefficient(
                    i, 
                    a.getCoefficient(i)
                     .multiply(b.getCoefficient(i)));
        }
        
        return c;
    }
    
    private static ComplexPolynomial 
        computeFFT(final ComplexPolynomial complexPolynomial,
                   final int scale) {
            
        final int n = complexPolynomial.length();
        
        if (n == 1) {
            return complexPolynomial.setScale(scale);
        }
        
        ComplexNumber omega = ComplexNumber.one(); 
        
        final ComplexNumber root  = 
                ComplexNumber
                        .getPrincipalRootOfUnity(n)
                        .setScale(scale);
        
        final ComplexPolynomial[] a = complexPolynomial.split();
        final ComplexPolynomial a0  = a[0];
        final ComplexPolynomial a1  = a[1];
        
        final ComplexPolynomial y0 = computeFFT(a0, scale);
        final ComplexPolynomial y1 = computeFFT(a1, scale);
        final ComplexPolynomial y  = new ComplexPolynomial(n);
        
        for (int k = 0; k < n / 2; k++) {
            final ComplexNumber y0k = y0.getCoefficient(k);
            final ComplexNumber y1k = y1.getCoefficient(k);
            
            y.setCoefficient(k,         
                             y0k.add(omega.multiply(y1k)).setScale(scale));
            
            y.setCoefficient(k + n / 2, 
                             y0k.substract(
                                     omega.multiply(y1k))
                                          .setScale(scale));
            
            omega = omega.multiply(root).setScale(scale);
        }
        
        return y;
    }
    
    private static ComplexPolynomial 
        computeInverseFFT(ComplexPolynomial complexPolynomial,
                          final int scale) {
        
        complexPolynomial = complexPolynomial.getConjugate();
        complexPolynomial = computeFFT(complexPolynomial, scale);
        complexPolynomial = complexPolynomial.getConjugate();
        divide(complexPolynomial, complexPolynomial.length());
        return complexPolynomial.setScale(scale);
    }
        
    private static void divide(final ComplexPolynomial cp, 
                               final int n) {
        
        final BigDecimal nn = BigDecimal.valueOf(n);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cp.length(); i++) {
            cp.setCoefficient(i, cp.getCoefficient(i).divide(nn));
        }
    }
    
    private static Polynomial multiplyViaKaratsubaImpl(final Polynomial p1,
                                                       final Polynomial p2) {
        final int n = Math.max(p1.getDegree(),
                               p2.getDegree());
        
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
            return multiplyViaNaive(p1, p2);
        }
        
        final int m = (int) Math.ceil(n / 2.0);
        
        final BigDecimal[] pPrime = new BigDecimal[m + 1];
        final BigDecimal[] qPrime = new BigDecimal[m + 1];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            pPrime[i] = p1.getCoefficientInternal(i)
                          .add(p1.getCoefficientInternal(m + i));
            
            qPrime[i] = p2.getCoefficientInternal(i)
                          .add(p2.getCoefficientInternal(m + i));
        }
        
        if (n > 2 * m - 1) {
            pPrime[m] = p1.getCoefficientInternal(n);
            qPrime[m] = p2.getCoefficientInternal(n);
        } else {
            pPrime[m] = BigDecimal.ZERO;
            qPrime[m] = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        }
        
        Polynomial r1 = getR1Polynomial(p1, p2, m);
        Polynomial r2 = getR2Polynomial(p1, p2, m, n);
        Polynomial r3 = getR3Polynomial(pPrime, 
                                        qPrime);
        
        final BigDecimal[] r4Coefficients = new BigDecimal[2 * m + 1];
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2 * m; i++) {
            r4Coefficients[i] = getCoefficient(r1, 
                                               r2, 
                                               r3, 
                                               i);
        }
        
        final Polynomial r4 = new Polynomial(r4Coefficients);
        
        final BigDecimal[] rCoefficients = new BigDecimal[2 * n + 1];
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2 * n; i++) {
            rCoefficients[i] = getCoefficient(r1,
                                              r2,
                                              r4,
                                              i,
                                              m);
        }
        
        return new Polynomial(rCoefficients);
    }
    
    private static BigDecimal getCoefficient(final Polynomial r1,
                                             final Polynomial r2,
                                             final Polynomial r3,
                                             final int i) {
        
        final BigDecimal term1 = r1.getCoefficientInternal(i);
        final BigDecimal term2 = r2.getCoefficientInternal(i);
        final BigDecimal term3 = r3.getCoefficientInternal(i);
        
        return term3.add(term1.negate()).add(term2.negate());
    }
    
    private static BigDecimal getCoefficient(final Polynomial r1, 
                                             final Polynomial r2,
                                             final Polynomial r4,
                                             final int i,
                                             final int m) {
        
        final BigDecimal term1 = r1.getCoefficientInternal(i);
        final BigDecimal term4 = r4.getCoefficientInternal(i - m);
        final BigDecimal term2 = r2.getCoefficientInternal(i - m * 2);
        
        return term1.add(term2).add(term4);
    }
    
    private static Polynomial getR1Polynomial(final Polynomial p,
                                              final Polynomial q,
                                              final int m) {
        
        final BigDecimal[] pCoefficients = p.toCoefficientArray(m);
        final BigDecimal[] qCoefficients = q.toCoefficientArray(m);
        
        final Polynomial pResultPolynomial = new Polynomial(pCoefficients);
        final Polynomial qResultPolynomial = new Polynomial(qCoefficients);
        
        return multiplyViaKaratsubaImpl(pResultPolynomial,
                                        qResultPolynomial);
    }
    
    private static Polynomial getR2Polynomial(final Polynomial p,
                                              final Polynomial q,
                                              final int m,
                                              final int n) {
        
        final BigDecimal[] pCoefficients = p.toCoefficientArray(m, n);
        final BigDecimal[] qCoefficients = q.toCoefficientArray(m, n);
        
        final Polynomial pResultPolynomial = new Polynomial(pCoefficients);
        final Polynomial qResultPolynomial = new Polynomial(qCoefficients);
        
        return multiplyViaKaratsubaImpl(pResultPolynomial, 
                                        qResultPolynomial);
    }
    
    private static Polynomial getR3Polynomial(final BigDecimal[] pCoefficients,
                                              final BigDecimal[] qCoefficients) 
    {
        final Polynomial pResultPolynomial = new Polynomial(pCoefficients);
        final Polynomial qResultPolynomial = new Polynomial(qCoefficients);
        
        return multiplyViaKaratsubaImpl(pResultPolynomial,
                                        qResultPolynomial);
    }
}

com.github.coderodde.math.ComplexNumber.java:
package com.github.coderodde.math;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

/**
 * This class implements basic facilities for dealing with complex number in the
 * Fast Fourier Transform algorithms.
 * 
 * @version 1.1.0 (Nov 24, 2024)
 * @since 1.0.0 (Nov 23, 2024)
 */
public final class ComplexNumber {
    
    /**
     * The real part of this complex number.
     */
    private final BigDecimal realPart;
    
    /**
     * The imaginary part of this complex number.
     */
    private final BigDecimal imagPart;
    
    public ComplexNumber(final BigDecimal realPart,
                         final BigDecimal imagPart) {
        
        this.realPart = realPart;
        this.imagPart = imagPart;
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructs this complex number as the real unity.
     */
    public ComplexNumber() {
        this(BigDecimal.ONE,
             BigDecimal.ZERO);
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructs this complex number.
     * 
     * @param realPart the real part.
     * @param imagPart the imaginary part.
     */
    public ComplexNumber(final double realPart,
                         final double imagPart) {
        
        this(BigDecimal.valueOf(realPart),
             BigDecimal.valueOf(imagPart));
    }
    
    /**
     * Construct this complex number as a real number with value 
     * {@code realPart}.
     * 
     * @param realPart the real part.
     */
    public ComplexNumber(final BigDecimal realPart) {
        this(realPart, BigDecimal.ZERO);
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber setScale(final int scale,
                                  final RoundingMode roundingMode) {
        
        return new ComplexNumber(realPart.setScale(scale, roundingMode),
                                 imagPart.setScale(scale, roundingMode));
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber setScale(final int scale) {
        return setScale(scale, 
                        RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }
    
    public BigDecimal getRealPart() {
        return realPart;
    }
    
    public BigDecimal getImaginaryPart() {
        return imagPart;
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber add(final ComplexNumber other) {
        return new ComplexNumber(realPart.add(other.realPart),
                                 imagPart.add(other.imagPart));
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber negate() {
        return new ComplexNumber(realPart.negate(),
                                 imagPart.negate());
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber substract(final ComplexNumber other) {
        return add(other.negate());
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber getConjugate() {
        return new ComplexNumber(realPart, imagPart.negate());
    }
    
    /**
     * Multiplies this complex number with the {@code other} complex number.
     * 
     * @param other the second complex number to multiply.
     * 
     * @return the complex product of this and {@code other} complex numbers. 
     */
    public ComplexNumber multiply(final ComplexNumber other) {
        final BigDecimal resultRealPart = 
                realPart.multiply(other.realPart)
                        .subtract(imagPart.multiply(other.imagPart));
        
        final BigDecimal resultImagPart = 
                realPart.multiply(other.imagPart)
                        .add(imagPart.multiply(other.realPart));
        
        return new ComplexNumber(resultRealPart,
                                 resultImagPart);
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber divide(final BigDecimal r) {
        return new ComplexNumber(realPart.divide(r),
                                 imagPart.divide(r));
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (!getClass().equals(o.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        
        final ComplexNumber other = (ComplexNumber) o;
        
        return realPart.equals(other.realPart) &&
               imagPart.equals(other.imagPart);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        if (imagPart.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
            return realPart.toString();
        }
        
        sb.append("(")
          .append(realPart)
          .append((imagPart.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) ? " + " : " - ")
          .append(imagPart)
          .append("i)");
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the {@code n}th principal complex root of unity.
     * 
     * @param n the root order.
     * 
     * @return a principal complex root of unity.
     */
    public static ComplexNumber getPrincipalRootOfUnity(final int n) {
        
        final double u  = 2.0 * Math.PI / (double) n;
        final double re = Math.cos(u);
        final double im = Math.sin(u);
        
        return new ComplexNumber(re, im);
    }
    
    public static ComplexNumber one() {
        return new ComplexNumber();
    }
    
    public static ComplexNumber zero() {
        return new ComplexNumber(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    }
}

com.github.coderodde.math.ComplexPolynomial.java:
package com.github.coderodde.math;

import static com.github.coderodde.math.Utils.powerToSuperscript;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 * This class implements the polynomial over complex number. We need this class
 * in the FFT algorithms.
 * 
 * @version 1.0.0 (Nov 23, 2024)
 * @since 1.0.0 (Nov 23, 2024)
 */
public final class ComplexPolynomial {
    
    private final ComplexNumber[] coefficients;
    
    public ComplexPolynomial(final int length) {
        this.coefficients = new ComplexNumber[length];
    }
    
    public ComplexPolynomial(final Polynomial polynomial) {
        this.coefficients = new ComplexNumber[polynomial.length()];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.length; i++) {
            coefficients[i] = new ComplexNumber(polynomial.getCoefficient(i));
        }
    }
    
    ComplexPolynomial(final ComplexNumber[] coefficients) {
        this.coefficients = coefficients;
    }
    
    public ComplexPolynomial setScale(final int scale) {
        final ComplexNumber[] coefficients = new ComplexNumber[length()];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.length; i++) {
            coefficients[i] = this.coefficients[i].setScale(scale);
        }
        
        return new ComplexPolynomial(coefficients);
    }
    
    public ComplexPolynomial shrinkToHalf() {
        final ComplexNumber[] coefficients = new ComplexNumber[length() / 2];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.length; i++) {
            coefficients[i] = this.getCoefficient(i);
        }
        
        return new ComplexPolynomial(coefficients);
    }
    
    public ComplexPolynomial getConjugate() {
        final ComplexNumber[] coefficients = new ComplexNumber[length()];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.length; i++) {
            coefficients[i] = this.coefficients[i].getConjugate();
        }
        
        return new ComplexPolynomial(coefficients);
    }
    
    public int length() {
        return coefficients.length;
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber getCoefficient(final int coefficientIndex) {
        return coefficients[coefficientIndex];
    }
    
    public void setCoefficient(final int coefficientIndex, 
                    final ComplexNumber coefficient) {
        
        this.coefficients[coefficientIndex] = coefficient;
    }
    
    public ComplexPolynomial[] split() {
        final int nextLength = coefficients.length / 2;
        final ComplexPolynomial[] result = new ComplexPolynomial[2];
        
        result[0] = new ComplexPolynomial(nextLength);
        result[1] = new ComplexPolynomial(nextLength);
        
        boolean readToFirst = true;
        int coefficientIndex1 = 0;
        int coefficientIndex2 = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.length; i++) {
            final ComplexNumber currentComplexNumber = coefficients[i];
            
            if (readToFirst) {
                readToFirst = false;
                result[0].setCoefficient(coefficientIndex1++,
                                         currentComplexNumber);
            } else {
                readToFirst = true;
                result[1].setCoefficient(coefficientIndex2++, 
                                         currentComplexNumber);
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    /**
     * Converts this complex polynomial to an ordinary polynomial by ignoring 
     * the imaginary parts in this complex polynomial and copying only the 
     * real part to the resultant polynomial.
     * 
     * @return an ordinary polynomial.
     */
    public Polynomial convertToPolynomial() {
        final BigDecimal[] data = new BigDecimal[length()];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < length(); i++) {
            data[i] = coefficients[i].getRealPart();
        }
        
        return new Polynomial(data);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (length() == 0) {
            return coefficients[0].toString();
        }
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        boolean first = true;
        
        for (int pow = length() - 1; pow >= 0; pow--) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                sb.append(getCoefficient(pow))
                  .append("x");
                
                   if (pow > 1) {
                      sb.append(powerToSuperscript(pow));
                   }
            } else {
                sb.append(" + ").append(getCoefficient(pow));
                
                if (pow > 0) {
                    sb.append("x");
                }
                
                if (pow > 1) {
                    sb.append(powerToSuperscript(pow));
                }
            }
        }
        
        return sb.toString().replaceAll(",", ".");
    }
}

Typical demo output
Na�ve: 7096 milliseconds.
Karatsuba: 3960 milliseconds.
FFT: 1866 milliseconds.
Na�ve agrees with Karatsuba and FFT: true.
Na�ve output: 63x???? + 87x???? - 3x???? - 35x???? - 6x???? - 154x???� - 162x???� + 28x??? - 1...
FFT output:   63x???? + 87x???? - 3x???? - 35x???? - 6x???? - 154x???� - 162x???� + 28x??? - 1...

Critique request
As always, I would like to receive any commentary you can come up with.

Why not have an interface PolynomialMultiplier, an classes Naive, Karatsuba, and FFT?

@greybeard Thought about it but was lazy and tired. I will include your suggestion in the follow up question if I get that far.

Everything is Util vs OOP
It would be a better design decision to describe the multiplication of polynomials as a behavior exposed by the Polynomial class (similarly to summation of polynomials) instead of pushing it into a util class.
To achieve that, you can employ the Strategy design pattern by introducing Polynomial.multiply() method expecting another polynomial and an instance of multiplication algorithm (a strategy).
Each version of multiply will delegate the job to the given strategy:
public class Polynomial {
    
    // other class members 
    
    public Polynomial multiply(Polynomial other, 
                               PolynomialMultiplier algorithm) {

        return algorithm.multiply(this, other);
    }
    
    // + two more overloaded versions of multiply()
}

Note, that parameter PolynomialMultiplier is an interface describing a multiplication algorithm (not your util class), that's a fairly concise and descriptive name (far more shorter than something along the lines of PolynomialMultiplicationAlgorithm), hence I've repurposed it to represent a strategy.
And here's the PolynomialMultiplier interface:
public interface PolynomialMultiplier {
    PolynomialMultiplier NAIVE = new NaiveMultiplier(); // a public static final constant initialized upon loading this interface
    PolynomialMultiplier KARATSUBA = new KaratsubaMultiplier();
    PolynomialMultiplier FFT = new FFTMultiplier();
    
    Polynomial multiply(Polynomial p1, Polynomial p2);

    Polynomial multiply(Polynomial p1, Polynomial p2, BigDecimal epsilon);

    Polynomial multiply(Polynomial p1, Polynomial p2, 
                        int scale, BigDecimal epsilon);
}

Each concrete implementation of the algorithm will be instantiated when PolynomialMultiplier interface is loaded into memory.
And you can hide concrete classes from the library user by making them package private (that's how, for instance, JDK hides the concrete implementation of java.util.stream.Stream).
Even from the perspective of code readability
var result = p1.multiply(p2, KARATSUBA); // use static import for PolynomialMultiplier.KARATSUBA

is easier to read then
var result = multiplyViaKaratsuba(p1, p2); // also needs static import

And you might consider treating one of the algorithms as a default one, and introduce a version that doesn't require specifying a strategy p1.multiply(p2).

Creating lots of temporary arrays
Physically splitting polynomials works and is probably the most elegant from the point of view of making code look "the least Fortran-like as possible", but it results in a lot of allocations of things that are going to be throw away almost immediately, lots of "object churn". Maybe no one cares, but there are some alternatives that reduce that:

Truncate the recursion: switch to O(n²) not-fast Fourier Transform for small n.
Keep the recursion as-is but pass a "view" down instead of a copy. Effectively that is what the iterative FFT does too but then it reorders the computation to be bottom-up and the representation of the view is just the index of the outer loop
Use an iterative FFT, which typically allocate one or even zero extra arrays up front instead of lots of them throughout. One neat thing here is that an iterative FFT normally needs the special bit-reversal permutation either before or afterwards to put the coefficients in the "usual order", but you don't need to do that when you're doing an FFT-based multiplication: the point-wise multiplication in the middle does not care about the order of the elements, and the bit-reverse permutation is its own inverse, so the inverses on both sides of the point-wise multiplication cancel each other.

On the hand it may be silly to worry about this when millions of BigDecimal objects are being created and then discarded (whatever we call it in a GC'ed language when an object becomes garbage-collectable) either way and almost unavoidably, except by not using BigDecimal. Does it help to use it? Considering that the roots are double-precision and the default scale is fairly low.
FFT trickery
The FFT (DFT for the purists since we're not talking about a particular algorithm here but about the transform independent of its implementation, but I'm going to ignore that from here on) of a real-valued sequence is conjugate-symmetric ie the second half of the result is the same as the first half, but mirrored and the imaginary component is negated. There are some things you can do, if you want, to get effectively more computation out of the same FFT by removing that redundancy.
Two real-valued sequences can be FFT'd for the price of one, well not really but close enough. If we have real-valued sequences A and B of length N, define sequence C as a complex-valued sequence such that C[k] = A[k] + i * B[k] (with i the imaginary constant) (note that this is not a computation as such, it's just creating an array of complex values out of two arrays of real values) and its FFT is denoted C', then the FFT of A is A'[k] = 0.5 * (C'[k] + conj(C'[N - k])) and the FFT of B is B'[k] = -0.5i * (C'[k] - conj(C'[N - k])), and since we really want the product of A and B we may as well compute that directly as AB[k] = (C'[k] + conj(C'[N - k])) * (C'[k] - conj(C'[N - k])) * -0.25i. C'[N - k] looks like a bug, accessing the array out of bounds when k = 0; what's supposed to happen is that the index wraps around to the start. C'[(N - k) & (N - 1)] would work for the usual power-of-two FFT, or just treat k = 0 as a special case.
There is also a trick to convert a real-valued sequence of length N into a complex-valued sequence of length N/2 by taking the even-index entries as the real components and the odd-index entries as the imaginary components, then after taking the FFT of that complex-valued sequence you can turn into what the FFT of the original real-valued sequence would be. I don't quite remember the formulas, it's more complicated than the first trick (it saves less time also).
There are similar tricks for the inverse FFT.
